# HttpClient constantly returns 404

Tags: c#, xamarin, httpclient

I am trying to call an endpoint from the Xamarin Forms application but I constantly get 404 error. The same endpoint works properly when I call it via Postman. Backend runs on a local k8s cluster and exposed via ingress.

```
public class LoginService
{
    string baseUrl = "http://myapp.com/api/Users/";
    HttpClient httpClient;
    public LoginService()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

public async Task<LoginResultDto> Login(ApplicationUserLoginDto applicationUserLoginDto)
    {
        LoginResultDto loginResultDto = null;
        var requestUri = new Uri(baseUrl + "login");
        await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(applicationUserLoginDto);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, content);
                var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                loginResultDto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResultDto>(responseJson);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //ToDo: Handle exceptions.
            }
        });
        return loginResultDto;
    }
}
```

I've checked the content I am sending to the endpoint, same with Postman's body. So is the request uri. I can't seem to figure out why I am getting 404.

Comment: what do the server logs show?  Have you tried generating the corresponding C# code from Postman?  https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/

Comment: @Jason it's not even hitting the server so there are no logs on neither ingress pod nor service pod. I tried Postmand autogenerated code and that one surprisingly returns 403...

Comment: of course its hitting the server, how else would it get a 404?  If it wasn't hitting the server it would timeout with no response.

Comment: @Jason yes actually you are right, but then I assume .net core automatically can't match the request with an endpoint then returns 404, but there are no logs. also postman generated code (using restsharp) returns 403.

Comment: you should be able to setup server logging to log any requests, even 404s.  If that doesn't work you may need to use Wireshark or something similar to compare the two requests

Comment: Try to take Fiddler or some other debugging proxy and just compare requests (url, query, headers, etc. ) from Postman and from your code. And then fix your code to remove differences between requsts.

Comment: You might want to try setting up something like fiddler to catch the request, you can then compare the requests your app makes with the ones postman makes and compare. Also, are you adding headers via postman that changes how the server responds? Like authentication headers etc?